# poisson convergence to normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

suppose that $x_1 , x_2, \ldots$ are independent poisson (mean${}=1$)

1) show that $\frac {y_n -n }{\sqrt n} \to z$ in distribution as $n \to \infty$ where $z$ belong to $N(0,1)$

where $y_n = x_1 +x_2 +x_3 + \cdots +x_n$

2) deduce that  $e^{-n} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{n^k}{k!}) \to 1/2$

in part one I use characterstic function of $s_n =\frac {y_n -n }{\sqrt n}$
the last step of my work $\exp(-t\sqrt n) ϕ_{y_n}\left(\frac t {\sqrt n} \right)$ but this not equal to characteristic of normal

please help me !

Comment: In (2) you have a typo.  It should be something like $e^{-n}\sum_{k=n}^\infty n^k/k! \to 1/2$.

Comment: Where you wrote $z= x_1 + \cdots+x_n,$ did you mean $y_n = x_1 + \cdots + x_n \text{?} \qquad$

Comment: yes  ... but ϕ in general what eq ? it has expectation in notation where is in the proof ? @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 2):

Note that 1) is a direct consequence of the central limit theorem, but maybe you are not allowed to use that fact?

The characteristic function of $\frac{y_n - n}{\sqrt{n}}$ can be computed to be $\exp(n(e^{it/\sqrt{n}}-1) - it\sqrt{n})$.
To show the exponent tends to $-t^2/2$ you can do l'Hôpital's rule (or recognize the limit as a derivative of a particular function).
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} [n(e^{it/\sqrt{n}}-1) - it\sqrt{n}]
\overset{x := 1/\sqrt{n}}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{itx} - 1 - itx}{x^2}
= \frac{it}{2} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{itx} - 1}{x}
= - \frac{t^2}{2}.$$

---

For 2), (with kimchi lover's correction), note that it suffices to show $P(y_n \ge n) \to 1/2$ because $y_n \sim \text{Poisson}(n)$.
$$P(y_n \ge n) = P\left(\frac{y_n -n}{\sqrt{n}} \ge 0\right) \to P(z \ge 0) = \frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: the idea if i prove that the characteristic of poisson have the same characterstic of N(0,1) it will done prove ? this true ?@angry

Comment: how you are find characterstic  please ?

Comment: ooh i know that by using characterstic eq of poisson but how i find  characterstic eq of poisson

Comment: @nikola Computing the characteristic function of the Poisson distribution is a direct computation from the definition. If you are still stuck, it is probably done on this site somewhere.

Comment: thnx alot may allah protect you

Comment: You wrote $x :=1/\sqrt n$ where you appear to need $x := t/\sqrt n. \qquad$

Comment: number 2 not clear for me .. why you take $p(y_n> n)$?